# Save complete complier output to txt or csv with "strict":true compiler option in typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, compiler-construction, strict

I have the following code in tsconfig.json which is opened in visual studio.
{
"CompileOnSave":false,
"CompilerOptions":{
"strict": true,
"skipLibCheck":true
},
"angularCompilerOptions":{
"fullTemplateTypeCheck":true,
"strictInjectionParameters":true,
"strictTemplates":true
}
}

1. I would want the list of errors identified by the compiler to be saved in a .txt or .csv file.
2. I need a list of errors identified across the workspace and not just for the files opened in the visual studio.
   Any inputs or suggestions?

I would need inputs/suggestions to try it out in the visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get a full project-wide report like this in your editor, but you can run the typescript compiler yourself easily enough.

```
tsc --noEmit > tsc-result.txt
```

That command will find the `tsconfig.json` in your project and use that to know what files to check.

The `--noEmit` flag means that compiled javascript will not be created for you.

The `> tsc-result.txt` will create a file with the contents of any found type errors.

Comment: Have you tried to automate this? I mean create a report by executing the strict compiler option outside of the code base. For example, Input - execution of automated script, output - .csv file with error report. By doing this I do not have to use open the code base/IDE.