# Script to automate the strict compiler option

Tags: compiler-errors, strict

I want to write a script that generates the strict compiler errors. The output should be similar to the results as in
[Save complete complier output to txt or csv with "strict":true compiler option in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76716322/save-complete-complier-output-to-txt-or-csv-with-stricttrue-compiler-option-i/76716380#76716380)

I had manually opened visual studio and had performed the creation of strict compiler error list and saved it in .csv/txt using the following command: tsc --noEmit > tsc-result.txt. This is done as mentioned in the following link. [Save complete complier output to txt or csv with "strict":true compiler option in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76716322/save-complete-complier-output-to-txt-or-csv-with-stricttrue-compiler-option-i/76716380#76716380)

I wanted to automate this process now where a click on the automatic script will create .csv/txt files with error list in it.